# Infinite scroll fired twice on refresh from the bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an infinite scroll set up with the following piece of code.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $("#home_content").height() - $(window).height()) {
        if (isLastPage) {
            foo();
        } else {
            bar(); // JQuery AJAX call
        }
    }
});
```

This is inside document.ready();
The ajax call doesn't happen when the server sends a flag for the last page. This works fine in a normal scenario. But when I press F5(Refresh) from the bottom of the page, two simultaneous scroll events are fired,and it bypasses the flag (as the second call happens even before the flag is set) and duplicate data is loaded.

The only thing i know is it happens at the end of document.ready() function. Anyone, any idea??

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

There is no much relevant code other than this.

And this happens only in FF 17.
In IE 9 when I do a fast scroll down, same scroll is fired twice

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727002/jquery-document-ready-fires-twice

Comment: What you have appears to be fine, but without seeing more code it's hard to diagnose the cause!

Comment: @Stevie: Its not document.ready() that is fired twice but window.scroll.

Comment: By the sounds window.scroll is only called when document.ready() is fired, so for you to be getting two scroll events, document.ready() surely **must** be getting fired twice? Without seeing more, it's hard to say what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a workaround as  we cannot see your complete code, but maybe thats can help:

```
var timeout;

$(window).scroll(function(){
      clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(function(){
      if  ($(window).scrollTop() >= $("#home_content").height() - $(window).height()){
                if (isLastPage){
                    foo();
                }else{
                    bar();//AJAX call
                }
            }
  },0);
});
```

Comment: made a small change. Increased the delay to 100 ms. Now works great in all the browsers. Thanks :) Btw let me know if there is any caveats if I do this.

Comment: You solved it man (y) and have bookmarked question so hats off for Question Poster too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this debounce routine for all sort of event calls. Clean and reusable.

```
// action takes place here. 
function infinite_scrolling(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $("#home_content").height() - $(window).height()) {
        if (isLastPage) {
            foo();
        } else {
            bar(); // JQuery AJAX call
        }
    }
}

// debounce multiple requests
var _scheduledRequest = null;
function infinite_scroll_debouncer(callback_to_run, debounce_time) {
    debounce_time = typeof debounce_time !== 'undefined' ? debounce_time : 800;
    if (_scheduledRequest) {
        clearTimeout(_scheduledRequest);
    }
    _scheduledRequest = setTimeout(callback_to_run, debounce_time);
}

// usage
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        infinite_scroll_debouncer(infinite_scrolling, 1000);
    });
});
```