# KnockoutJs v2.3.0 : "cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element"

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, document-ready

Problem:

In an existing application, I'm adding a new feature which uses knockout to display a grid and some additional information. I load some of the data at the start and prepare subscriptions which load other data using ajax, create viewmodel in Razor view to inject server-side variables, and then bind it (it does not matter if I pass html node or not, I have same problem).
Upon page load, "cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element" error appears in console, and all of the html elements which use `if`, `with` or `template` bindings are empty.

The only occurrences of "applyBindings" in entire project are in my view, and in knockout source. Debugging shows that it is called twice, both times from $(document).ready

When I remove apply bindings from code, and call it later manually using console, it works.

Comment: I finally solved mine by returning `{ controlsDescendantBindings: true }` in the `init` function of the binding handler. See [this](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is already on SO: [jQuery $(document).ready () fires twice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10727036/408643)

Theme of the application was moving/manipulating html elements, and  tag with viewmodel initialization was inside same html view which was manipulated later. Moving  to separate section which is rendered in head solved problem.