# jQuery code firing twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, jquery-load

I don't know why and how, but my jQuery code appears to be firing twice on any event.

Here's a part of my code:

`commmon.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".fpbtn-one").click(function() {
        console.log("Click recorded!"); // Gets logged twice on click
        $(this).parent().next().slideToggle();
    });

    // The rest of the code...

});

$(window).load(function() {

    console.log("Setting up slides"); // Gets logged 2 on page load

    // These get initialized twice
    $("#div-1").responsiveSlides({
        auto: true,
        pager: true,
        pause:true,
        nav: false,
        timeout: 3000,
        speed: 500,
        maxwidth: 482,
        namespace: "transparent-btns"
    });

    $("#div-2").responsiveSlides({
        auto: true,
        pager: false,
        pause:true,
        nav: false,
        speed: 2000,
        maxwidth: 320,
    });

});
```

---

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head><link href="/assets/css/jquery.qtip.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/custom/themes/1st-formation-theme/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/assets/css/efControl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/script/jquery/jquery.qtip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/script/jquery/plugin.efiling.full.js"></script>

<meta charset="utf-8" /><script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM||(NREUM={}),__nr_require=function a(b,c,d){function e(f){if(!c[f]){var g=c[f]={exports:{}};b[f][0].call(g.exports,function(a){var c=b[f][1][a];return e(c?c:a)},g,g.exports,a,b,c,d)}return c[f].exports}for(var f=0;f<d.length;f++)e(d[f]);return e}({"4O2Y62":[function(a,b){function c(a,b){var c=d[a];return c?c.apply(this,b):(e[a]||(e[a]=[]),void e[a].push(b))}var d={},e={};b.exports=c,c.queues=e,c.handlers=d},{}],handle:[function(a,b){b.exports=a("4O2Y62")},{}],YLUGVp:[function(a,b){function c(){var a=m.info=NREUM.info;if(a&&a.agent&&a.licenseKey&&a.applicationID){m.proto="https"===l.split(":")[0]||a.sslForHttp?"https://":"http://",g("mark",["onload",f()]);var b=i.createElement("script");b.src=m.proto+a.agent,i.body.appendChild(b)}}function d(){"complete"===i.readyState&&e()}function e(){g("mark",["domContent",f()])}function f(){return(new Date).getTime()}var g=a("handle"),h=window,i=h.document,j="addEventListener",k="attachEvent",l=(""+location).split("?")[0],m=b.exports={offset:f(),origin:l,features:[]};i[j]?(i[j]("DOMContentLoaded",e,!1),h[j]("load",c,!1)):(i[k]("onreadystatechange",d),h[k]("onload",c)),g("mark",["firstbyte",f()])},{handle:"4O2Y62"}],loader:[function(a,b){b.exports=a("YLUGVp")},{}]},{},["YLUGVp"]);</script>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />


<link href="/assets/custom/files/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />
<link href="/assets/custom/images/system/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" />
<link href="/assets/custom/images/system/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" />
<link href="/assets/custom/images/system/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" />

<meta content="" name="description" />
<meta content="" name="keywords" />
<meta content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" name="ROBOTS" />
<title>Some title</title>


<link href="/assets/custom/files/css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/custom/files/css/base.css?=v1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/custom/files/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/custom/files/css/font-awesome-ie7_min.css">
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/custom/files/js/adobe-type.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- BODY STUFF IN HERE (REMOVED) -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/custom/files/js/jquery-mmenu-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/custom/files/js/jquery-anystretch-stand-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/custom/files/js/common.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/custom/files/js/modernizr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/custom/files/js/responsiveslides_min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/custom/files/js/socialmedia.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/custom/files/js/jquery_atooltip_min.js"></script></div>

<script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM||(NREUM={});NREUM.info={"beacon":"beacon-4.newrelic.com","licenseKey":"204ccc8db2","applicationID":"1825150","transactionName":"YVNVYBACWxFTWxFcWVgZYkYLTFwMVl0dG0ZeRg==","queueTime":0,"applicationTime":187,"ttGuid":"","agentToken":"","userAttributes":"","errorBeacon":"jserror.newrelic.com","agent":"js-agent.newrelic.com\/nr-361.min.js"}</script></body>
</html>
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: use 'one' instead of click

Comment: @CodingAnt that does not make any sense.

Comment: was just a suggestion , can you provide jsfiddle for that

Comment: A jsFiddle won't help here. The same thing is happening to the rest of the code.

Comment: Can you post your html?

Comment: @TilwinJoy What exactly would you like to see?

Comment: If you want a solution you should post your html or a fiddle. Its all up to you.

Comment: The only reason for the handler firing twice is if you're adding it twice. I don't see any reason for that in what you've posted. I suspect you have duplicate code in your actual site.

Comment: @Barmar check out my HTML - i am not adding it twice. The code is in `common.js`

Comment: If you can't replicate this in jsfiddle, can you provide a link to the actual site?

Comment: use e.stopPropagation();

Comment: http://www.1stformations.co.uk/frontpage/

Comment: @chuckfinley i don't see any multiple logs in the page you shared other than something like `setting up slides`

Comment: @TilwinJoy That's the problem he's talking about. There's only one `console.log()` that does that in the `$(window).load()` handler, it shouldn't be logging twice.

Comment: I'm not sure where it's happening, but it looks like something is reloading common.js dynamically.

Comment: @Barmar i added a debugging point in `$(window).load()`. Everything is  being executed twice. This is just unreal.

Comment: I see that. When it hits that debugging point the second time, it's it's in a file called VM####, where #### is a number that changes each time. That's why I think the file is being reloaded dynamically. I don't see where that's happening, though.

Comment: does this have anything to do with the js animating `html` ? will it trigger another load after the animation?

Comment: I highly doubt it. It was working just fine yesterday

Comment: I moved all JS includes to the head of the page and it solved the issue. It works but i don't know why :(

Comment: @chuckfinley you should really add that as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your code was manipulating the element that the code was loading into?

This answer may be the reason why it was happening:

[jQuery $(document).ready () fires twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727002/jquery-document-ready-fires-twice)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the stuff in the body inside divs.

example. `<div id = "menu"><script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/custom/files/js/jquery-mmenu-min.js"></script> </div>`

I hope that works. :)

Answer (score 0):

be careful for beginning use good practice when calling jquery :

```
!function( $ ) {
   your code

}( jQuery )
```

like that you avoid conflict...

Then be careful when adding js script in html, you can add it twice, for example you call one js in a html file, ok but in the js you load in callback for example another page with the js inside, it will call twice your code.... i had the same probleme before with a recursive call, the js never stop to call it !!
in the main page it is better if your js will be called in several files otherwise you have to debug it....

moreover you don't paste all your code we can't help you, we can just tell in my opinion.... not a good advices often...

Answer (score 0):

May be you have included your script file `commmon.js` twice. Check your references to it in your code.

Answer (score -1):

It might be event bubbling. Use `event.preventDefault()`, it will prevent the default event from occuring or `event.stopPropagation()` will prevent the event from bubbling up.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".fpbtn-one").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        console.log("Click recorded!"); // Gets logged twice on click
        $(this).parent().next().slideToggle();
    });

    // The rest of the code...

});
```

Comment: The same thing is happening for every single block of code. This can't be it

Comment: What about `$(window).load()`? That doesn't bubble.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest explanation is that you have included the common.js twice by mistake.

Look into individual scripts and see if you have referenced common.js on top of your main file.

Comment: Please look at the question and you will notice that i am not including the file twice.

Comment: @chuckfinley firebug reported the script is imported again dynamically.

Answer (score -3):

Your relevant code is required, but from the snippets above; try putting all the codes in the document ready method.

Comment: It's already in the ready handler. If it weren't, it probably wouldn't fire at all, not fire twie.