# event handler handles selector twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I have this kind of handler

```
$(".mydiv").on('click', function(e){

// some logic
$(this).toggleClass('active');

//other logic

});
```

I have a bug where this event is triggered twice, and I see that on the first run `this` is `".mydiv"` and on the second run `this` is `".mydiv.active"` and it seems that `".mydiv.active"` is added during the event handling to the list of nodes that match the selector

Is there a way around this?

This is the fuller code:

```
$(".filter_view:not(.mobile-view) .filter_content .cat, .filter_view:not(.mobile-view) .filter_content .check_area, .mobile-view .search_filter").on("click", function(e){
        debugger;

        $(this).toggleClass("active");
                e.stopPropagation();

// rest of the logic

});

<span class="check_area col-xs-4 col-md-2">
    <input class="filter_checkbox" id="Neve" name="Neve" type="checkbox" value="Neve"> 
    <label class="filter_checkbox_label" for="Neve">Neve</label>
</span>
```

Basically, the parent is `.filter_view`, but on mobile it has a `.mobile-view` class, so on mobile I want the `search_filter` to do the logic and on not mobile when clicking on the `check_area` (which is checkbox + label) and on `.cat` (category)

When checking the event on the first and second triggers, the first target is the label (what I clicked) yet the 2nd time the target is the checkbox (which I didn't click)

Even though I stopped propagation, could it be that bootstrap (or some other framework lib) has an event of when a label is clicked the checkbox is `click()`ed as well?

Comment: Have you tried e.preventDefault(); ?

Comment: check whether the event registration code is called twice

Comment: @ArunPJohny is most likely spot on.  The only way an event handler will be executed twice is if it is being called twice, usually because the code that assigns it is run twice.

Comment: Add a console logging before `$(".mydiv").on('click', function(e){` and see whether the message is logged twice..

Comment: I added logging, the handler is called once. Using inspect the events registered to that node is only one event

Comment: We'll need to see markup then, as what you've got above shows nothing that can help you.

Comment: ok, I tried to simplify it, I will add the markup and full selector

Comment: what is `cat`? is it a parent of `check_area`?

Comment: `cat`s are spans under common parent .filter_content. it is not directly related to check_area

Comment: does "check_area" have a parent class(in the whole DOM) in the onclick selector list?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(".mydiv").on('click', function(e){

// some logic
$(this).toggleClass('active');

e.stopPropagation();

});
```

stopPropagation() prevents bubbling of the event.

Comment: I've stopPropagation, before and after toggleClasses doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Add `$(".mydiv").off('click');` before you bind the click event, the code you showed us is probably being called twice, which binds the event handler twice. Maybe you have it in an init() function which is called more than once?

Comment: There is a slim chance the event is being fired twice: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10727036/2295592