# Why is jQuery Prepending Twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason I am having an issue where .prepend() is occurring twice.

My code is as follows:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-1">Menu One</li>
    <li id="menu-item-2">Menu Two</li>
    <li id="menu-item-3">Menu Three</li>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function() {

    var html = '<li id="menu-item-0">Menu Zero</li>';
    $('#menu').prepend(html);

});
```

The fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/2Ljf9qn8/, is working properly.

Is there any known reason why this would produce the following?

- Menu Zero
- Menu Zero
- Menu One
- Menu Two
- Menu Three

Any help is greatly appreciated.

FYI: I did remove the prepend outside of doc ready, just in case the page was loading twice, but still no luck.

Comment: its only prepending once for me

Comment: Its working fine for me.

Comment: even for me in jSfiddle its prepend once

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727002/jquery-document-ready-fires-twice

Comment: That's not something that jQuery would just randomly do. Something is making that happen more than once.

Comment: Confirm u r using js only once

Comment: Use `console.log` to log out when `ready` fires, that way you can see if the event is causing it.,

Comment: I suspect you may have some issues with event listeners. Are you prepending on click (or hover etc) in your application? I'm guessing this is not the whole code.

Comment: Thank you all, @JameyD - console logging ready helped me see that my script was loading twice. Always something simple ... thanks again.

Comment: Did you find out why this was happening? I am having the same issue and have no event listeners other than doc ready and that is only firing once. Driving me mad!