# How to stop the jQuery .load() function from firing more than once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to make a function *strictly* only callable once? As in, once per time the page is loaded.

I'm using :

```
$( document ).ready( function() { 
    $( "#targetDiv" ).load( "http://www.example.com #specificElementID" );
});
```

I'm finding that if you click all over the page lots of times whilst it's loading, that it sometimes seems to load twice? Is there a way of preventing this action from happening more than once? I was under the impression that having `$( document ).ready( function() { ...` would help me to achieve this. But it does not appear to be the case!

Comment: Your posted code would be called only once for sure. `I'm finding that if you click all over the page lots of times whilst it's loading, that it sometimes seems to load twice?` I guess your observation is wrong. If you are using any click event, then post relevant code

Comment: This code snippet is good. Show us other code. Try to represent this problem at JSFiddle.

Comment: Nothing in code shown would cause this issue. Is the same code being loaded again?

Comment: I'm not sure why this kind of question without any way to replicate issue can be upvoted... What's wrong with SO? I will upvote it if OP can send at least link where this issue can be checked

Comment: @jamiec I think regarding dupe and question here, it would be a workaround to a XY problem

Comment: @A.Wolff I think you're probably right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ready` handler would not be called more than once in normal cases. However, if your file is loaded twice, this will cause the ready handler to be called twice.

Using a boolean flag may hide the real problem (but you still have to see what's the root issue):

```
var _ready = false;
$( document ).ready( function() { 
    if (_ready) { return; }
     _ready = true;
    $( "#targetDiv" ).load( "http://www.example.com #specificElementID" );
});
```

For more information, see this related question: [jQuery $(document).ready () fires twice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10727002/1420197)

Comment: That ready handler will only ever be called once unless the code is loaded again. This answer doesn't make sense

Comment: @charlietfl My brother had exactly the same problem and that's how we solved it. I wonder if the load method calls the ready handler twice or something related to that. It seems that [`iframe`s can create such a behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727002/jquery-document-ready-fires-twice#comment13935697_10727036).

Comment: @charlietfl I edited my answer.

Comment: @IonicăBizău Ya but because (see comment): `Avoid using src="#" attribute, because it is loading the same page on parent window and inside iframe, that's why it looks like code is called twice. Remove src attribute or set it to "about:blank" to avoid such behavior`  So the same script is called twice

Comment: @A.Wolff Agree. Without more code provided by OP it's hard to say what's going on. We can only speculate. :)

Answer (score 1):

add this line

```
$("#some_id").unbind('change');
```

before

```
$("#targetDiv").load("http://www.example.com #specificElementID");
```