# When does document.ready() get invoked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the below parsing phase,

[image]
When does $document.ready() get executed?

Comment: When the DOM get loaded.

Comment: at the beginning of the "Interactive Phase"

Comment: Do you understand now overexchange?

Comment: @AmanuelBogale Can I say that `ready` is not the event name in `$(document).ready()` instead it is a wrapper function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simple anwser when the DOM/Document Object Model Gets Loaded when the HTML Gets Loaded..

[Docs](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

> Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page
>   Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

---

**I also explained it well here to:**

https://discuss.codecademy.com/t/window-onload-vs-document-ready/19000

Where i said:

jQuery document.ready will run your code when the HTML is all ready, but before images and other resources have finished. This is the earliest possible time that you can change the DOM with JavaScript, so it's widely used. In Modern Browsers like google chrome it is replaced by [DOMContentLoaded3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded). Again more info Here.

So by your picture:
[image]

$document.ready(fn) will be loaded at the beggining of interactive face  when the Dom has "completed" loading...

Answer (score 2):

> When does $document.ready() get executed?

`.ready()` can be executed multiple times

> [`.ready( handler )`](http://api.jquery.com/ready) 
>   Returns: `jQuery`
>   Description: Specify a function to execute when the `DOM` is fully loaded.
>
> If `.ready()` is called after the `DOM` has been initialized, the new
>   handler passed in will be executed immediately.
>
> The `.ready()` method can only be called on a jQuery object matching
>   the current document, so the selector can be omitted.

```js
n = -1;

function ready() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].textContent += "ready " + ++n + "\n";
}

$(document).ready(ready);

$(document).ready(function() {
  ready();
  $(document).ready([function() {
    ready()
  },
    function() {
      $(document).ready(function() {
        ready();
        $(document).ready([
          function() {
            ready()
          }, function() {
          ready()
          if (n === 5) $(document).ready(function() {ready()})
        }]);
      
      })
    }
  ])
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<body>
  <p></p>
</body>
```

See soruce at [ready.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core/ready.js#L75)

```
if ( document.readyState === "complete" ||
    ( document.readyState !== "loading" && !document.documentElement.doScroll ) ) {

    // Handle it asynchronously to allow scripts the opportunity to delay ready
    window.setTimeout( jQuery.ready );

} else {

    // Use the handy event callback
    document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", completed );

    // A fallback to window.onload, that will always work
    window.addEventListener( "load", completed );
}
```