# Will $(document ).ready() fire if the code which checks is inserted after the event happend?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-listener, document-ready

I have a page where some additional Javascript code is downloaded to the page after the page itself has been loaded, (for example when the user clicks a button, a call is made to the server which pulls down an extra .js file).

If that additional code has a check for DOM ready like so..

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
   console.log( "will they see me?" );
 });
```

Will that line be printed to the console since by the time this code runs on the page, the jQuery DOM ready event has already fired?

In other words, does this check need to be present when the actual event happens or would it also fire after the event happened?

Comment: Couldn't you just try it and see?

Comment: I wish I could but this is not my page and would take some time to setup locally, I know I am lazy but I was hoping some jQuery gurus here who knew off hand could just tell me and save me the trouble.

Comment: Or [read the docs](https://api.jquery.com/ready/): _"If .ready() is called after the DOM has been initialized, the new handler passed in will be executed immediately."_

Comment: @AbuMariam You've got a console; that's all you need to run little JS snippets.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is both [well documented](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) and trivially testable.

Comment: "I am lazy but I was hoping some jQuery gurus here who knew off hand could just tell me and save me the trouble" – this is the exact opposite of how you're supposed to use Stack Overflow.

Comment: See [When does document.ready() get invoked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36143711/when-does-document-ready-get-invoked)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You've got a method to test that in your question already:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   console.log("will they see me?");
});
```

Run that in the console, and watch the message get printed out.