# jQuery one function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to create a function jQuery one() on `$(document).ready`, I know the syntax for click events, and selectors, but I don't know how to make a function that would run only on document ready, and only once, with switch statements in it?

Comment: Call the function on document ready.  That will run it once.

Comment: Do you have any code ? `$(SELECTOR).on(HANDLER)` will work just fine....

Comment: The `ready` event only occurs once per page. If you're seeing duplication, check that the entire script is only included once. Also, [jQuery $(document).ready () fires twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727002/jquery-document-ready-fires-twice)

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski `.ready()` can be called multiple times, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/36144130/

Comment: Yes "The ready event only occurs once per page" is true, but if you call `.ready` multiple times it will call the callback multiple times. You are saying, in effect, that you want to shoot your foot twice but you only want one hole in your foot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the function will only be run once unless there are event listeners that call it more than once.

Rayon's answer is not the best. Put the function once() inside $(document).ready function so it won't pollute the global namespace. It also ensures a faster resolve of the function name because of JavaScript's scope chains.

Put it outside if it's a reusable component so you could easily move it in a separate file and call from different contexts. This would apply if you are developing a library or a big application.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  once();
 function once() {
   alert("See, this happens only once");
  };
});
```

```html
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div>
Test
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function one() {
   alert("Once called");
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    one();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Just declare your function as you normally would and call from within document.ready.

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

```
function one() {
   console.log("Do one");
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    one();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var handler = function() {
  alert('Called!');
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  handler();
  $('#elem').one('click', handler);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="elem">Only Once!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be absolutely sure the function is run only once, you can use a flag in case it's accidentally called again:

```
var flag = false;

function one() {
    if (!flag) {
        flag = true;
        //do stuff
    }
}

//.ready()
$(function() {
   one();
});
```

If the function is unique to one page, you can declare it within the `.ready()` call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.Callbacks()` with parameter `"once"`

```js
function once() {
  alert("once")
}

var callbacks = $.Callbacks("once");

callbacks.add(once);

$().ready(callbacks.fire); // call `once`

$().ready(callbacks.fire); // this will not call `once`

$().ready(function() {
  alert("do other stuff")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```