# Javascript: call function inside another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a simple code which calls a function func1() when the user presses "A". Inside func1() I would like that, if a certain condition is satisfied, another function func2() is called and func1() is stopped.(A short example of what I am doing is shown below). How can I do this? Thank you!

```
  <html>
    <head>
    </head>



    <body> 

      <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
          document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {            

              else if  (e.keyCode === 83) { // If "S" is pressed the game starts
                 func1(); 
              }
          }); 
        }) 
          function func1(){   
             $(document).ready(function() {                 

                  document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {   
                    var myVar = Math.floor( Math.random() *6);


                       if (myVar>3){ 
                        func2();                           
                        }

            }, false);  
        });
      } 

      function func2(){ 
      /////  
      }             

</script>
```

Comment: you are nesting `$(document).ready()` inside of func1 which will prevent the code inside from ever firing. The `ready` event has already fired, which is when your javascript was evaluated the first time. When you call func1, it is waiting to add the event listener `click` until the document has the `ready` event triggered for a second time, which isn't going to happen.

Comment: @JoeLissner That's incorrect in this case. Unlike browser implementations of event handlers, jQuery will queue up the `.ready()` callbacks and fire them even if the event has already executed. See [here](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) - _"However, jQuery's .ready() method differs in an important and useful way: If the DOM becomes ready and the browser fires DOMContentLoaded before the code calls .ready( handler ), the function handler will still be executed. In contrast, a DOMContentLoaded event listener added after the event fires is never executed."_

Comment: @War10ck well I learned something today :)

Comment: @JoeLissner See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36143711/when-does-document-ready-get-invoked/

Answer (score 1):

You need to refactor your code and remove the unnecessary call to `$(document).ready()`. I'm assuming it's the click event you want to disable...
Let me know if it's the keypress you want to disable.

**EDIT**: 
I edited the code to remove the func2 event listener when 's' key is pressed, and add click event listener to document when func2 is called.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
    $('.keypressed').html(String.fromCharCode(keyCode));
    if (keyCode === 83) { // If "S" is pressed the game starts
      document.removeEventListener('click', helper2);
      func1();
    }
  });
});
//refactored the handler function to stand on its own
function helper(e) {
  var myVar = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);

  console.log('myVar in func1() = ', myVar);


  if (myVar > 3) {
    func2(e);
    return;
  }
}

function helper2(e) {
  
  console.log('func2() click event called!')
}

function func1() {
  document.addEventListener("click", helper, false);
}

function func2(e) {
  //disable the click event listener
  document.removeEventListener('click', helper);
  document.addEventListener('click', helper2)
  console.log('called func2()');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
</head>
<div class="keypressed"></div>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. I am afraid that there is still something that does not work correctly. What I did notmention is that func2() also has a "click" event listener. I want to disable func1()'s event listener when I am i func2() and vice versa. Any idea?

Comment: you can do the same thing I did in func2 in func1. just externalize the event handler function, and use it in a call to removeEventListener(). I'll edit my code to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.off()` to remove event listener attached to jQuery object. `.ready()` call within `func1` is not necessary.

`else..if` should be `if`, unless there is `if` statement not included at `javascript` at Question.

```
$(document).on("keydown", function() {
  if (/* condition */) {
    $(this).off("keydown");
    func1();
  }
});
```

```
function func1() {
  $(document).on("click", function() {
    if (/* condition */) {
      $(this).off("click");
      func2();
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems there is a problem if I add $(document) instead of document.