# document.ready function called again after submit button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

In doc.ready I am dynamicaly generating a select option list via parsing an html table -> **selected_Test_Platforms**
When I click the submit button I want to submit the selected options and run main()

The main() function does a lot of calculation and finaly prints some google charts.

Every time I click the Submit button, the main() function is exectuted correctly, **but shortly after that the document.ready function is also called and everything is overwritten!**

**Why is the document.ready function called again even if I only want to call main?**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
//...
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------//
// find Affected TestPlatforms and add them to the selector
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------//
    $('tbody tr').each(function() {
        var TestPlatform = $(this).find('td.Affected').text(); //Affected Test Platforms
        aquireTestPlatforms(TestPlatform);
    });
    addTestPlatformsToSelector();
});

function main(){

//...multiple lines of calculation...

// example of one Chart
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawSOWCoverageChart);
    function drawSOWCoverageChart(){
    
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Type', 'Count'],
            ['Positive Tested and Tested with Restrictions', posSOWTestCoverage],
            ['other states', SOWReqCount-posSOWTestCoverage]
        ]);

        var options = {
            title: 'Test Coverage',
            width: 600,
            height: 400,
            legend: { position: 'right',alignment: 'center', maxLines: 3 },
            chartArea: {left:80, bottom:20},
            colors: ['#109618', '#DC3912']
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('SOWCoverageChart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
//...
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Report manipulation options:</a>
      </div>

      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <select id="selected_Test_Platforms" class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" data-live-search-placeholder="Search" data-actions-box="true">
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <select id="selected_SIL_relevant" class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" data-live-search-placeholder="Search" data-actions-box="true">
              <option value='all' selected>-All-</option>
              <option value 'Safety Relevant'>Safety Relevant</option>
              <option value 'QM'>QM</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <button onclick="main()" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: document.ready is called again because the `form` is being submit on the button click and the page is reloading...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because the default action of the `<button>` element is to submit the form. Basically you are executing `main()` **and reloading the page**: this causes the `$(document).ready(...)` event to fire again. You can simply call `event.preventDefault` in the button function, or use `<button type="button">` to override form submission behavior.

The simplest solution:

```
<button onclick="main()" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Submit</button>
```

Otherwise, you will have to capture the event and prevent default behavior, i.e.:

```
function main(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    // Rest of the code here
}
```

With regards to the second solution: it is always better to attach event handlers to elements instead of using inline JS. We can give your button an ID:

```
<button id="submitButton" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

And then simply attach the click event listener to it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tbody tr').each(function() {
        var TestPlatform = $(this).find('td.Affected').text(); //Affected Test Platforms
        aquireTestPlatforms(TestPlatform);
    });
    addTestPlatformsToSelector();

    $('#submitButton').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // All of main() code can go in here
    });
});
```