# coordinate setInterval and setTimeout to loop jQuery-each

Tags: jquery, settimeout, setinterval, nested-loops

I use an endless loop of a `each()` with `setInterval` and `setTimeout` in this way:

```js
var links = [];
links = ['zuinfos-1-tab', 'zuinfos-2-tab', 'zuinfos-3-tab', 'allgemein-tab'];
var init = 5000
var z = 0;
var n = new Date().getTime()

setInterval(function() {
  $(links).each(function(index, value) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('a#' + value).trigger('click');
      var j = new Date().getTime()
      var diff = j - n
      console.log(z + '\t' + index + '\t' + value + '\t' + diff);
    }, 5000 * index)
  });
  z++;
}, init * 4)
```

All is fine, but the first `setInterval` comes too late. I have to set it to `init * 4`, because there are four elements in each-loop. At the beginning it should start with `init * 1`.

I tried with a counter like this:

```
}, z==1?init:init*4 )
```

But this does not work.

Comment: To debug this we really need to see a working example, so that we can see the timing in action, and also to understand exactly what this code does as I am 99% certain there's a less convoluted way of doing whatever you require.

Comment: [Similar issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68470984/2181514) - nesting multiple `setTimeout` inside a `setInterval` will cause you no end of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with

```
setInterval(..., z==1?init:init*4)
```

is that the interval is only calculated once, not on every loop.

If you move the callback to its own function, you can call it from an initial setTimeout then from a setInterval on that first call, eg:

```
function autoLinkClicker()
{
    $(links).each(function(index, value) {
        setTimeout(function() { ... }, 5000 * index);
    });
}

setTimeout(function() { 
    autoLinkClicker();
    setInterval(autoLinkClicker, init*4);
}, init);
```

Comment: Thanks, freedomn-m.
This is exactly what i did now.